# A question on Measure Theory (easy one)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I think this needs a philosophical answer.

> (1) It is know that every countably additive measure is finitely additive one, and
>
> (2) every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra.

BUT,

> If one uses the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, according to (1) this measure is finitely additive, but as a consequence, many open sets (not interval) in $[0,1]$ will be not measurable!

The question that I want it to be answered is:

> Can we use countably additive measure by means of finitely additive one OR this means that when a countably additive measure satisfies a property, so is finitely additive one. What is the benefit on (1).

Please someone explain this, I am confused !

Comment: Can you give an example of your contradiction? i.e. could you give us an example of some open sets that aren't measurable?

Comment: @Layman I don't know where your confusion lies, but every open set is certainly Lebesgue measurable. Also, there are finitely additive extensions of Lebesgue measure under which all sets of reals are emasurable.

Comment: Also, every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the at most  countable union of open intervals.

Comment: Hmm, I have serious doubts about the truth of your statements. All open sets are measurable w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on any interval: this follows immediately from the facts that (1) every open interval is measurable and (2) every open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of open intervals ($[0,1]$ inherits its open sets from $\mathbb R$), right?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker You said,  there are finitely additive extensions of Lebesgue measure under which all sets of reals are measurable?? How this possible ?

Comment: @Layman This follows from a result in functional analysis, the Hahn-Banach theorem. Still, why do you believe there is no finitely additive measure under which all open sets are measurable?

Comment: @Layman if something is finitely additive it doesn't mean it isn't countably additive. That is the Lebesgue measure is both countably and finitely additive, so that set is indeed measurable with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker the Hahn-Banach Theorem is such a nice theorem. I didn't even realize it showed up here!

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker But I do if you consider a sequence of measurable sets for which their union is also measurable (if I am not wrong). But as I understand is: finitely additive as restriction of a countably additive not as an extension as you said. Maybe this is my confusion.

Comment: @DanZimm Could you explain what you have written in your last comment.

Comment: @Layman If you restrict Lebesgue measure to the algebra (sic!) generated by open intervals, you will get a finitely additive measure under which not every open set is measurable. But that doesn't mean there are no finitely or even countably additive measures under which every open set is measurable.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I think you get my point. Yes that I meant that exactly. So now you understand my fault. Please explain this in details for me. When will be true to say every countably additive measure is finitely additive one ? I would appreciate you help.

Comment: @Layman it's in essence what Michael was saying - you're, in some sense, mixing up your algebras and your measures

Comment: @DanZimm Yes, I feel so. But I really need one you to help me out. I need a detailed answer of this .

Comment: @Layman A countably additive measure is always finitely additive.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Please explain, when countably additive measure is finitely additive. Should the measure be defined on a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @DanZimm Any comment on my last comment (to MichaelGreinecker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitoons vary, but the following should be fairly representative. Let $X$ be a set. A family $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$ is an *algebra* if

1. $X\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}$
2. Whenever $A\in\mathcal{A}$, then $X\backslash A\in\mathcal{A}$
3. Whenever $A_1\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_2\in\mathcal{A}$,then $A_1\cup A_2\in\mathcal{A}$.

A family $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$ is a *$\sigma$-algebra* if

1. $X\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}$
2. Whenever $A\in\mathcal{A}$, then $X\backslash A\in\mathcal{A}$
3. Whenever $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of elements of $\mathcal{A}$, then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{A}$.

The definitions only differ in condition 3. Now every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra, for if $A_1\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_2\in\mathcal{A}$, then by letting $A_n=\emptyset$ for $n\geq 3$, we get $$A_1\cup A_2=A_1\cup A_2\cup\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\ldots=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{A}.$$ 
It is slightly more difficult to see that an algebra may fail to be a $\sigma$-algebra.

A *finitely additve measure*  is a function $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ with domain an algebra such that

1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.
2. $\mu(A)\geq 0$ for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$.
3. If $A_1\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_2\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$, then $\mu(A_1\cup A_2)=\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2)$.

A *measure*  is a function $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ with domain a $\sigma$-algebra such that

1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.
2. $\mu(A)\geq 0$ for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$.
3. If $A_n\in\mathcal{A}$  for all $n$ and $A_n \cap A_M=\emptyset$ whenever $m\neq n$, then $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n).$$

Since every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra, a measure is defined on an algebra. Now if $\mu$ is a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $A_1\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_2\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$, then we can set $A_n=\emptyset$ for $n\geq 3$. Then $$\mu(A_1\cup A_2)=\mu(A_1\cup A_2\cup\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\ldots)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)$$ $$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)=\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2)+0+0+\ldots=\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2),$$
so every measure is also a finitely additive measure.

**Remark:** Definitions vary, and sometimes measures are defined even on algebras, in which case the definition of 3. has to hold only for the case that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{A}$, which is automatic for $\sigma$-algebras. But by an important, if somewhat unintuitive, theorem, called the *Caratheodory extension* theorem, one can always enlarge in that case the measure to a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, we can say every countably additive measure is finitely additive only if $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{A}$ for some $\{A_n\}\in\mathcal A$. That why it is not true when restricting the Lebesgue measure to an algebra generated by open intervals.

Comment: @Layman I'm not sure what you mean, Lebesgue measure restricted to the algebra generated by open intervals is finitely additive. It is only that the algebra generated by open intervals does not include all open sets.

Comment: What I mean is: every countably additive measure on an algebra $\mathcal A$ is finitely additive only if $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{A}$ for some $\{A_n\}\in\mathcal A$. Otherwise the measure is only finitely additive.

Comment: "is finitely additive only if" ... "Otherwise the measure is only finitely additive." I don't get what you are writing. Every countably additive measure on an algebra, if defined as in my remark, is finitely additive for exactly the reason I gave in my post.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I mean every countably additive measure on an algebra $\mathcal A$ when this condition $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal{A}$ for some $\{A_n\}\in\mathcal A$ exist. Otherwise it is not true to say " every countably additive measure is finitely additive".

Comment: @Layman There always exists such a sequence in an algebra: $\emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset,\ldots$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am sorry for wasting your time. The problem is my understanding.

Comment: @Layman Don't worry. Take your time, that stuff can be very confusing on a first encounter.